# Proof checking for Rolles Theorem

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

This was a proof given for Rolles Theorem : Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b], a<b$, and differentiable on $(a, b)$. Suppose $f(a)=$ $f(b)$. Then there exists $c$ such that $c \in(a, b)$ and $f^{\prime}(c)=0$.

Proof: If $f$ is constant on $[a, b]$ then $f^{\prime}(c)=0$ for all $c \in[a, b]$. Suppose there exists $x \in(a, b)$ such that $f(x)>f(a)$. (A similar argument can be given if $f(x)<f(a))$. Then there exists $c \in(a, b)$ such that $f(c)$ is a maximum. Hence  we have $f^{\prime}(c)=0$.

> By what can we say that if at any point f(x)>f(a) we are surely having a c in the region (a,b) which is the maximum? Is it becauss of the fact its being continuous and **bounded** hence it must have a local maxima/minima , problem doesnt state its bounded but if its not that then continuity will not apply isnt in some interval ?

Comment: Any continuous function in a closed interval $[a,b]$ is bounded and has a maximum. The condition $f(x)>f(a)$ only adds that in this case the maximum can't be achieved at $a$ or $b$, so it must be achieved somewhere in the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: The theorem is that any continuous function on a closed interval always attains its maximum and minimum. In particular, this implies that a continuous function is bounded on a closed interval—it doesn't need to be separately assumed.

Comment: I understood thanks @Mark GregMartin , but the proof doesnt deals with the case when the end points might be a maxima /minima isnt ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax It does. If both the maximum and minimum are achieved at end points, then since $f(a)=f(b)$ it follows that $f$ is constant. That case appeared in the first sentence of the proof. Otherwise, either the maximum or minimum is achieved in $(a,b)$. The proof only deals with the case when the maximum is there, since for minimum it is the same idea.

Comment: Oh yeah i now see thanks a lot

Comment: @Mark why both maximum and minimum at end points ? We can also have a case where there is just maximum at end points isnt ? Or minimum , what would the scenario there?

Comment: I think we can give the reasoning that if maximum/minimum occurs at end points a , b  then , there will exist minimum and maximum respectively too in (a,b) from here we can conclude that which is same as second case of letting f(x) >f(a) , please tell if anything is wrong to what i said

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer Either both are at end points, or at least one of them is in $(a,b)$. These two cases complete each other, and it is enough to deal with them. Of course there are also subcases (just one is achieved at end points) but we don't need this for the proof.